# Project is linked with BigQuery and Google Analytics but not exporting data to BigQuery

Tags: firebase

I have linked Firebase Analytics to BigQuery. I don’t see any dataset for my firebase app’s analytics in BigQuery.

Firebase’s project integrations tab says for BigQuery that the “Project is linked but not exporting data”.

I have attached a screenshot also.

Can anyone help me get exporting to work?

[screenshot for data set not created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbKSS.png)
[screen shot for google analytics and bigquey already linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwJfx.png)